# Create border and title for each column in `facet_wrap`

Tags: r, ggplot2, border, facet-wrap

I want to put black borders with labels and titles around each facet in `facet_wrap`.
Something similar to this:

[image]

Sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(gear = factor(gear, levels = c(4, 3, 5))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  facet_wrap(~am + gear)
```

Comment: maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652284/how-to-change-color-of-facet-borders-when-using-facet-grid and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220242/ggplot2-outside-panel-border-when-using-facet/46236791

Comment: just to clarify - you want the border not around each facet, but around each column of ?

Comment: Thank you for the links, I'm looking into them. Yes, I wouldn't like around each facet per-se but around each column in this case.

Comment: I actually wouldn't really mind if it will be just around the columns, as I can arrange the facets order to match what ever order I want.

Comment: I think what you want to achieve is not easy without some hacking. I wonder if you may not want to overthink the aesthetic of your plot - maybe simply draw borders around the entire plot? You could plot your facets in several distinct plots and easily add a border and title [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175766/draw-border-around-certain-rows-using-cowplot-and-ggplot2)

Comment: @Tjebo I was thinking about it as my "plan B". I was hoping maybe someone will have a better/easier solution :)

Comment: How are you trying to split up gears?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood the question, but under `facet_wrap()`. Next I just want to border each column

Comment: @Tjebo - Thank you for the bounty!

Comment: With pleasure - I learned from it too :) I guess one could consider accepting the answer? There seems to be not much activity here otherwise..

Comment: I accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by manually adding to the ggplot `gtable`:

```
library(tidyverse)    
library(grid)
library(gtable)

p <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(gear = factor(gear, levels = c(4, 3, 5))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  facet_wrap(~am + gear)

g <- ggplotGrob(p)

# add basic black rectangle round the columns
gt <- gtable_add_grob(g, 
                     gList(
                      rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = "black", lwd=3, fill=NA)), 
                      rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = "black", lwd=3, fill=NA))),
                     t=7, b=13, l=c(5, 9))
# look
# grid.newpage(); grid.draw(gt)

# add title above columns
tit1 <-  textGrob("title1", x=0, hjust=0) ; tit2 =  textGrob("title2", x=0, hjust=0) 
gt <- gtable_add_rows(gt, grobHeight(tit1) + unit(0.5, "line"), 0)
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, gList(tit1, tit2), t=1, l=c(5, 9))
# draw
grid.newpage(); grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Tjebo; I picked up wee bit from [Baptiste's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471093/baptiste) answers, and he provides a quick guide [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/gtable.html)

Comment: There may be another way now with this cool new package : https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/gggrid/gggrid.html