# only having outermost border when using facet_grid() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to be able to create a plot with just the outermost borders when using facet_grid(). This has been answered before here: [ggplot2 outside panel border when using facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220242/ggplot2-outside-panel-border-when-using-facet)

but this example will not work for me as I need the facet labels to be on the bottom of the graph and when using this solution there is a space between each of the grids on the top border.

```
#Example for stack 

  df <- structure(list(Lake = c("Lake_x", "Lake_x", "Lake_x", "Lake_x"
  ), Site = c("Lake_x-1", "Lake_x-2", "Lake_x-3", "Lake_x-4"), 
  Season = structure(1:4, levels = c("Season1", "Season2", 
                                     "Season3", "Season4"), class = "factor"), Nitrogen = c(450L, 
                                                                                            390L, 930L, 950L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
  
  df$Season
  #order Season
  df$Season <- factor(df$Season, levels=c("Season1", "Season2", "Season3", "Season4"))
  
  ggplot(df, aes(fill = Site, y = Nitrogen , x = Site)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 6), width = 0.4) +
    scale_fill_manual(
      "Site",
      values = c("black", "black", "black", "black"),
      
    ) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
          text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans"),
    ) + labs(title = 'Area 8', x = "", y = expression(paste("Total Nitrogen (µg/L)"))) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))  +  
    scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.2, 0.2)) +
    theme(legend.position ="none") +
    facet_grid(~Season, scales = "free_x", switch = 'x') +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"), 
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.placement = "outside") + theme(plot.title.position = 'plot', 
                                               plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

What current output looks like
[image]

I would like the three black horizontal borders in the plot to be removed so it looks like one plot.

Note: I know in this example the plot could be made without a facet_grid() but this is just an example and my real plots for sure need to use facet_grid so I need a solution to the outside border when using this function.

Comment: `panel.border = element_blank(),`?

Comment: that removes the whole border. I want it to look like a regular plot so it has a square outside border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of any option to achieve that via `theme()` or ... but a hacky approach similar to option 2 in the answer/post your referenced would be to get rid of the panel border using `panel.border=element_blank()` then fake an outer panel border using `geom_hline` and `geom_vline`:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat_vline <- data.frame(
  xintercept = c(-Inf, Inf),
  Season = c("Season1", "Season4")
)

dat_hline <- data.frame(
  yintercept = c(-Inf, Inf)
)

ggplot(df, aes(fill = Site, y = Nitrogen, x = Site)) +
  geom_vline(data = dat_vline, aes(xintercept = xintercept), lineend = "square") +
  geom_hline(data = dat_hline, aes(yintercept = yintercept), lineend = "square") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 6), width = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    "Site",
    values = c("black", "black", "black", "black"),
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.2, 0.2)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  facet_grid(~Season, scales = "free_x", switch = "x") +
  labs(title = "Area 8", x = "", y = expression(paste("Total Nitrogen (µg/L)"))) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans"),
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside"
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]